# How to use default namespace in dom4j selectNodes xpath expressions?

Tags: xpath, xml-namespaces, dom4j

I'm using Dom4J to parse some Maven Pom files. When I use Pom files without a default namespace, everything works fine. For example:

```
Document pom = DocumentHelper.parseText(
                 "<project>" +
                 "   <groupId>xx.gov.xxx.sistema.xxx</groupId>" + 
                 "   <artifactId>sis-teste</artifactId>" + 
                 "   <packaging>war</packaging>" + 
                 "</project>");
//below works fine
String groupId = pom.selectSingleNode("/project/groupId").getText()
```

But if my Pom file defines a default namespace, it stops working:

```
Document pom = DocumentHelper.parseText(
                 "<project xmlns=\"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd\">" +
                 "   <groupId>xx.gov.xxx.sistema.xxx</groupId>" + 
                 "   <artifactId>sis-teste</artifactId>" + 
                 "   <packaging>war</packaging>" + 
                 "</project>");
//NullPointerException!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
String groupId = pom.selectSingleNode("/project/groupId").getText()
```

The weird thing is that `pom.selectSingleNode("/project")` works fine.

**How do I make my xpath query to work with the default namespace?** I'd like to query just for `"/project/groupId"`and get the groupId node.

Comment: If you dont want to have to change your query you will need to dive into the rabbit hole of namespaces in XPath. I suggest you read this http://www.edankert.com/defaultnamespaces.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My hacky solution was just to remove the namespace of the pom file before creating the Dom object. Not really beautiful, but it works fine and life's go on.

Answer (score 4):

Like so:

```
    Document pom = DocumentHelper.parseText(
            "<project xmlns=\"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd\">" +
            "   <groupId>xx.gov.xxx.sistema.xxx</groupId>" +
            "   <artifactId>sis-teste</artifactId>" +
            "   <packaging>war</packaging>" +
            "</project>");
    Map<String, String> nsContext = new HashMap<>();
    nsContext.put("p", "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0");
    XPath xp = pom.createXPath("/p:project/p:groupId");
    xp.setNamespaceURIs(nsContext);
    String groupId = xp.selectSingleNode(pom).getText();
    System.out.println(groupId);
```

**UPDATE**

After a little closer look at the DOM4J code, this is possible, if you can tolerate setting a global namespace uri map:

```
    Map<String, String> nsContext = new HashMap<>();
    nsContext.put("p", "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0");
    DocumentFactory.getInstance().setXPathNamespaceURIs(nsContext);

    Document pom = DocumentHelper.parseText(
            "<project xmlns=\"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd\">" +
            "   <groupId>xx.gov.xxx.sistema.xxx</groupId>" +
            "   <artifactId>sis-teste</artifactId>" +
            "   <packaging>war</packaging>" +
            "</project>");
    String groupId = pom.selectSingleNode("/p:project/p:groupId").getText();
    System.out.println(groupId);
```

A more localized solution would be to use a `SAXReader` and configure it with a specialized `DocumentFactory`, not the global one.

Comment: It is a correct answer to use xpaths with namespaces, but it forces me to change all the xpath expressions and all api calls. It looks like there's no way to select a namespace when doing selections directly in the Document object.